# How to avoid crash when using Renci in SSIS

Tags: ssis, reference, ftp

I am using Renci to access SFTP files in my SSIS package

my package has only one control "Script Task" to execute some .net code, my coede required Renci reference so I added renci.sshnet.dll to my references.

the problem is that when I try to execute my package I get this error message

[image]

I tried commenting out the script to see what cause the error

I got this line that make the execution fails and send this error message

```
using (var sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
```

I tested my code in Windows Forms C#.net it is working perfectly

here is the code in my package

```
    public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        string host = @"myhost.mydomain.com.au";
        string username = "MyUserName";
        string password = "MyPassword";

        string remoteDirectory = "/SourceFolder/";
        string localDirectory = @"C:\Test\";

        using (var sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
        {
            sftp.Connect();
            var files = sftp.ListDirectory(remoteDirectory);

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                string remoteFileName = file.Name;
                if ((!file.Name.StartsWith("."))) //&& ((file.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Today)))

                    using (Stream file1 = File.OpenWrite(localDirectory + remoteFileName))
                    {
                        sftp.DownloadFile(remoteDirectory + remoteFileName, file1);
                    }
            }
        }


            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Comment: `TargetInvocationExceptions` has an inner exception that contains the root problem. You need to find our what the inner exception is (`InnerException` property). Without that information, we cannot help you.

Comment: Also, you you are using SFTP protocol, so use [tag:sftp] tag, not [tag:ftp]. FTP and SFTP are two different protocols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution

1- open command prompt as admin

2- cd o the folder where "gacutil" is installed

3- make sure renci.sshnet.dll is in c drive

4- register using gacutil